# Matplotlib not showing one line in Raspberry pi, but it does in Ubuntu

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a script which works perfectly in Ubuntu 16.04 but doesn't in Raspbian.

I'm plotting this data (`datosPlot.txt`):

```
26-01-2017_17:54:57 7.630 25.43
26-01-2017_17:55:01 7.630 25.39
26-01-2017_17:55:06 7.631 25.42
26-01-2017_17:55:11 7.645 25.38
26-01-2017_17:55:15 7.630 25.41
26-01-2017_17:55:19 7.632 25.37
```

First column is date and time, second is pH and third is Temperature

In raspbian, the script only plots the third column (Temperature) with the date/time (first column), with the right scale.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.animation as animation

datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S'))
def animate(i):
    dates, ph, temp = np.genfromtxt('datosPlot.txt', converters={0: datefunc}, usecols=(0,1,2), invalid_raise=False, unpack=True)
    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax2.grid(True)

    ax1.plot_date(dates, ph, ls='-', marker='.', color='red', label='pH')
    ax1.set_ylabel('pH')
    ax2.plot_date(dates, temp, ls='-', marker='.', color='blue', label='Temperatura C')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Temperatura C')

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
    lines = ax1.get_lines() + ax2.get_lines()
    plt.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines], loc=2)
    fig.tight_layout()
fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Grafica pH y Temperatura')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx() 
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Interestingly, it does read the second column (pH) because the graph shows the right scale, but not the line. Also, if I change `ax1` and `ax2` in the last lines (`ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)` and `ax2 = ax1.twin()`) I then get pH plotted but not Temperature.

Comment: Can you post in the question what versions of mpl are you using?

Comment: This is wild guess, but it is possible that the backend matplotlib is using on Rasbian is different one than on Ubuntu. If something went wrong with drawing to the backend system then line wouldn't be drawn. This shouldn't happen though. Not in wildest dreams. But do check anyway. matplotlib.get_backend(). If it isn't the same, install the one from Ubuntu on Rasbian and try drawing with it.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I will not be able to try it until tomorrow. I'll update

Comment: @Lucas The problem was different versions of mpl. Now both are `1.5.1` and it's working properly (with python3). Thank you